# Can't use @type/node with typescript 3.2

Tags: typescript, types

I can't use any type of @type/node with typescript 3.2

My tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "target/www/app",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["src/app/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Version of typescript : 3.2.2
Version of @type/node : 11.13.5

I have this error message :

> error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types  field in your tsconfig.

I understand the error but didnt find a way of fixing it.

UPDATE :

```
npm ls --depth=0
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.8
+-- @angular/animations@7.2.13
+-- @angular/cli@7.3.8
+-- @angular/common@7.2.13
+-- @angular/compiler@7.2.13
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.13
+-- @angular/core@7.2.13
+-- @angular/forms@7.2.13
+-- @angular/language-service@7.2.13
+-- @angular/platform-browser@7.2.13
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.2.13
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-server@^7.1.4
+-- @angular/router@7.2.13
+-- @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.0
+-- @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.17
+-- @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.8.1
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.1.1
+-- @nguniversal/express-engine@7.1.1
+-- @ngx-translate/core@11.0.1
+-- @ngx-translate/http-loader@4.0.0
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.16
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.6
+-- @types/node@11.13.5
+-- @types/webpack-env@1.13.9
+-- bootstrap@4.3.1
+-- codelyzer@4.5.0
+-- core-js@2.6.5
+-- jasmine-core@2.99.1
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@1.9.1 - 3
+-- karma@4.0.1
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.5
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.2
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- moment@2.24.0
+-- ng-jhipster@0.9.3
+-- ngx-build-plus@7.8.1
+-- ngx-cookie@4.1.2
+-- ngx-infinite-scroll@7.1.0
+-- ngx-ui-switch@8.0.1
+-- ngx-webstorage@3.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.14.7
+-- protractor@5.4.2
+-- rxjs@6.3.3
+-- ts-node@7.0.1
+-- tslib@1.9.3
+-- tslint@5.11.0
+-- typescript@3.2.4
`-- zone.js@0.8.29

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-server@^7.1.4, required by @nguniversal/express-engine@7.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: jquery@1.9.1 - 3, required by bootstrap@4.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: popper.js@^1.14.7, required by bootstrap@4.3.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.3
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.3
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.3
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.3
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.3.5, required by tar@4.4.8
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.8
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by tar@4.4.8
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.3, required by tar@4.4.8
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.3.5, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by minipass@2.3.5
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.3, required by minipass@2.3.5
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.3.5, required by minizlib@1.2.1
```

Comment: I have an option like this in my config file: `"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],` . also when i check the directory all my types are per dependency/module a directory

Comment: can you please paste the output of `npm ls --depth=0` ?

Comment: @jucypers i added npm ls log, and try typeRoots with no success

Comment: .Alll the solutions I have found, all propose what you already have.  maybe you can check what is outdated, but more than that I dont know.  `npm outdated`.  as well as you can clean your unusued packages `npm prune`  and `npm install` for missing if any

Comment: maybe check (all but last) comment of this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115665/cannot-find-name-require-in-angular-7typescript-3-1-3.            declare const require: any;

Comment: yet another one:  same SO post.   .add it in  /tsconfig.json AND ./src/tsconfig.app.json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My probleme was in tsconfig.app.json an another file using the tsconfig.json and extend it.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

types was override :

```
"types": []
```

Removing this line fix the problem.